# Dask dataframe groupby and applying custom functions

Tags: python, dask

I have this function that I am trying to apply to a dask dataframe that calculates cooling assuming certain storage capacity and rate limits.  It takes a 15-minute timestep value of cooling a building uses and returns the amount a certain storage rate can accommodate.

```
   def cooling_kwh_by_case(row, storage_capacity, storage_rate):
    if ((row['daily_cooling_kwh'] <= storage_capacity/row['cop']) & (row['max_cooling_kw'] <= storage_rate/row['cop'])):
        return row['daily_cooling_kwh']
    elif ((row['daily_cooling_kwh'] <= storage_capacity/row['cop']) & (row['max_cooling_kw'] > storage_rate/row['cop'])):
        daily_groupby = net_load_w_times.groupby('index')['electricity_cooling_kwh'].apply(lambda x: sum(min(x,storage_rate/(4*row['cop']))))
        return daily_groupby.loc[(row.building_date)]
    else:
        n_largest = 1
        daily_groupby = net_load_w_times.groupby('index')['electricity_cooling_kwh'].apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(n_largest).sum())
        while ((daily_groupby.loc[(row.building_date)]) <= (storage_capacity/row['cop'])) & (n_largest < net_load_w_times.groupby('index')['electricity_cooling_kwh'].count()):   
            n_largest += 1
            daily_groupby = net_load_w_times.groupby('index')['electricity_cooling_kwh'].apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(n_largest).sum())
        return min(storage_capacity/row['cop'],net_load_w_times.groupby('index')['electricity_cooling_kwh'].apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(n_largest-1).sum()).loc[(row.building_date)])
```

When I apply it, this is my error message.

```
        <ipython-input-22-88e243d194c6> in cooling_kwh_by_case()
         16         n_largest = 1
         17         daily_groupby = net_load_w_times.groupby('index')['electricity_cooling_kwh'].apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(n_largest).sum())
    ---> 18         while ((daily_groupby.loc[(row.building_date)]) <= (storage_capacity/row['cop'])) & (n_largest < net_load_w_times.groupby('index')['electricity_cooling_kwh'].count()):
         19             n_largest += 1
         20             daily_groupby = net_load_w_times.groupby('index')['electricity_cooling_kwh'].apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(n_largest).sum())

ValueError: Not all divisions are known, can't align partitions. Please use `set_index` to set the index.
```

I think the issue I'm running into is the way I try and calculate the value I want for the else statement which are the cases where the cooling kwh is larger than the storage_capacity parameter.  To calculate this value, I apply a function to find when the sum of the largest 15-min cooling kwh values for the day exceeds the storage_capacity.  I then return the sum of the largest values.

The dataframe that I am trying to groupby in the function to return a value is called net_load_w_times:

```
                          time  electricity_cooling_kwh  \
building_id                                                
2           2016-07-05 19:00:00                 0.050000   
2           2016-07-05 22:00:00                 3.200000   
2           2016-07-05 16:00:00                 5.779318   
2           2016-07-05 20:00:00                 1.888300   
2           2016-07-05 18:00:00                 7.490000  

             electricity_heating_kwh  total_site_electricity_kwh iso_zone  \
building_id                                                                 
2                           0.000000                   19.529506   MISO-E   
2                           0.045235                    6.310719   MISO-E   
2                           0.000000                   22.514705   MISO-E   
2                           0.018624                   13.474863   MISO-E   
2                           0.005464                   18.192927   MISO-E   

                    index        date  
building_id                            
2            2|2016-10-24  2016-10-24  
2            2|2016-03-05  2016-03-05  
2            2|2016-08-14  2016-08-14  
2            2|2016-03-05  2016-03-05  
2            2|2016-03-05  2016-03-05
```

Desired Output:

Given `cooling_kwh_by_case(row, 8, 5)` it outputs:

7.717618 because this is the max cooling kWh it can add up until 8.

Answer (score 0):

Dask dataframes are lazy and do not work within control flow like if-else statements or for loops.  I recommend trying to find solutions within the pandas API, like the `where` method.